# How to set callback URL in Google checkout?

Tags: php, notifications, google-checkout

How to set callback URL in Google checkout ?

and How can I get notification from GoogleCheckout after payment ?

Comment: How about http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API.html ?

Comment: @fabrik : tried. But not able to get what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Google Checkout Support](http://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?answer=134463):

> The API callback URL you specify tells
>   Google Checkout where to send
>   notifications about new orders, order
>   state changes, and other events. If
>   you integrate your order processing
>   system, you must specify a callback
>   URL.
>
> To add or edit your API callback URL:
>
> 1. Sign in to Google Checkout.
> 2. Click the Settings tab. Click Integration.
> 3. Enter your callback URL in the 'API callback URL' box.
> 4. Click Save.

Comment: @Gaurav: As far as I am aware, no. PHP can receive notifications but Google has to know which URL to send them.

Comment: In paypal we can let paypal know on ehich url notification has to be sent. Can't we set this url, by posting some data?

Comment: @Gaurav: Not directly. However, if it's a must, one option would be to use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and emulate the manual configuration process programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to specify the callback URL on your server:

http://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?answer=134463

After that you can receive various notifications from Google Checkout about the status of your order:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Processing.html

Here is a link to a PHP Google Checkout library that demonstrates how to process order notifications on your server:

http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-php-sample-code/